# Code stuck when querying CosmosDB in java integration test

Tags: java, spring, rx-java, integration-testing, azure-cosmosdb

I'm writing integration test for an API.
In DAO class, when I try to fetch data from Cosmos DB using AsyncDocumentClient instance queryDocuments method, program has stuck indefinitely.

This is how my function call looks like:

```
Iterator< FeedResponse<Document>> getDataFromCosmos = asyncDocumentClientInstance.queryDocuments(collectionLink, querySpec, feedOptions).toBlocking().getIterator();
```

**This is happening only when I run the test cases (in test mode).
But the code and API is working fine when I run in normal mode.**

This is how my test class looks like:
(I'm doing integration testing, not unit testing)

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)

public class ApiTest extends TestngInitializer

{

@Autowired

ServiceImpl serviceImpl;

    @Test
    public void apiTest()
    {
    RequestClass requestObject = new requestObject();
    // hardcoding requestObject data variables using setters

    ResponseClass response = serviceImpl.apiMethod(requestObject,HttpHeaders);

    //Assertions on response

    }

}
```

My TestngInitializer class looks like (Setting path to get all spring beans)

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:/META-INF/biz-context.xml","classpath:/META-INF/service-context.xml"})

public class TestngInitializer
{

}
```

When I try to debug line by line, when control has reached `BlockingObservable.java`, control is waiting indefinitely for some thread to finish which is not the case when I run the code in normal mode.

```
BlockingUtils.awaitForComplete(latch, subscription);
```

If anyone can help me on this, that would be great.

Here is the small reproducible code I tried as well:

```
@Test
public void testDBLocally()
{
    AsyncDocumentClient asyncDocumentClient = readDocumentClient(); //calling below function
    FeedOptions feedOptions = new FeedOptions();
    feedOptions.setEnableCrossPartitionQuery(true);
    String collectionLink = "/dbs/link_to_collection";
    SqlQuerySpec querySpec = new SqlQuerySpec("select * from some_document c ");

    //here I tried two approaches
    //first approach using iterator
    Iterator<FeedResponse<Document>> iterator = asyncDocumentClient.queryDocuments(collectionLink,querySpec,feedOptions).toBlocking().getIterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext())
    {
        //control stuck indefinitely at iterator.hasNext()
        //control never reached inside while loop
    }

    //second approach using last()
     FeedResponse<Document> response = capsReadDocumentClient.queryDocuments(collectionLink, querySpec, feedOptions).toBlocking().last(); //control stuck here
     documentList = response.getResults(); //control never reached here

}

public AsyncDocumentClient readDocumentClient() {
    String HOST = "https://azure-cosmosdb.documents.azure.com:443/";
    String MASTER_KEY = "SOME_MASTER_KEY"; 
    return new AsyncDocumentClient.Builder()
            .withServiceEndpoint(HOST)
            .withMasterKeyOrResourceToken(MASTER_KEY)
            .withConnectionPolicy(ConnectionPolicy.GetDefault())
            .withConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.Session)
            .build();
}
```

Comment: The usual cause of such hangups is that one or more threads are deadlocked. What schedulers are you using and where? For instance, if both your test code and the client query are running on the same scheduler, you will definitely have deadlock.

Comment: Hi, No I'm not using any scheduler. I'm just running test case in my local IDE.

Comment: if you provide a small reproducer it would be easier to solve this

Comment: Hi @özkanpakdil, I had edited my question and had added code which I tried and explains my issue in short. Thanks.